# How do you source a shell script with dart.io in the current process?

Tags: bash, dart, dart-io

`Process.run` (and all variants) complain about using the '.' and 'source' commands. Is there a built-in way to do this with the run methods or is there a particular executable I can try calling that will mimic bash's source command?

Comment: I don't know dart, but after reading the doc briefly, it's clear to me that `Process.run` invokes the process directly, in a non-shell context. If you want to `source`, what you need to do is to invoke the shell interpreter, e.g., bash, so you need run `bash -c 'blah blah'`, or put `source` and other commands in a shebanged, executable script, and run that script.

Comment: The `source` (aka `.`) command runs a script *in the current shell*. Since dart isn't a shell, the command doesn't make much sense in that context. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @GordonDavisson He probably just wants to export some env vars.

Comment: The script I need to source does export some env vars and specifically, adds some new programs to $PATH. My goal is to be able to source this script programmatically through my Dart application so that I can then invoke Process.run() on the new programs added to my $PATH.

Answer (score 3):

All these commands have a `runInShell` argument. If this doesn't fix it use `shell -c ". xxx"`

If you `Process.run('. somescript.sh, runInShell: true);` and then `Process.run('someexecutable');` you gained nothing because when the first call ends the created environment dies with it. 
I assume what you want is

```
Process.run('. somescript.sh && someexecutable', runInShell: true);
```

Comment: From the docs, runInShell is false by default - so without setting that to true, and env variables set via Process.run() should be added to the current environment in which my application is running, right?

Comment: Also, can you edit your answer to include a call to Process.run() as an example?

Comment: @Crunchex: No, there's no way for a subprocess (which AIUI is what Process.run creates -- in any of its modes) to set environment variables in the parent process.